# Is IP over FC still crazy complex?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ip, fibre-channel

In the link below, it is explained that 4 years ago IP over FC was *crazy complex*:

> [How do I set up IP over FC?](https://serverfault.com/questions/300699/how-do-i-set-up-ip-over-fc)

Is that still the case on CentOS 6?

Comment: Maybe you need to describe your scenario more fully. You could start with listing the hardware - servers (and how many), HBAs, FC switches if applicable.

Comment: It still is. What problem are you trying to solve? I've been happy with 10GbE for most applications these days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not see any reason to do this nowadays.
You have modern ethernet NICs with high bandwidth and throughput.
Also you do not introduce all kind of inflexibilities introduced with FC and IPFC.

Some of them:

You can't aggregate FC HBAs -> combine both 10GbE and get 20GbE. You can have them active/standby or use both active/active and get 5Gbps on each.

Disabling port != failover.  Can and will cause disruptions.

And if you still want FCIP on RHEL6, yes it is still huge pain to build and configure for stable, production environment.

Hope this helps.