# Can I use Emulex fibre channel ports to set up a network between my servers?

Tags: fibre-channel

I recently got my hands on a couple of old Fujitsu servers, all of which contain two PCIe fibre channel cards (Emulex ones). I also own a fibre channel switch. Is it possible to use the FC ports as networking interfaces to communicate via TCP/UDP or is FC solely intended for the SCSI protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically, probably not. Some drivers did support IPFC on a couple different operating systems, but its probably not maintained. Even a few years ago this was dreadfully obscure, see: [How do I set up IP over FC?](https://serverfault.com/questions/300699/how-do-i-set-up-ip-over-fc)

In theory IP over a fancy lossless network with multipathing is nice. It can work, but the complexity just isn't worth it for many use cases. Commodity Ethernet is cheaper.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link. I think I will stick to ethernet.