# How do I set up IP over FC on OpenSolaris / Illumos?

Tags: ip, fibre-channel, illumos

[This article](https://serverfault.com/questions/300699/how-do-i-set-up-ip-over-fc) implies that it's easy, but gives no details.

I have a double QLogic card in my OmniOS server, connected via two fibre-optic cables to SFP adaptors in my Procurve switch.  What I would *really* like is to aggregate the two connections so I have one double-capacity IP connection between switch and server.

I've looked at `cfinfo`, `cfadm`, `cfgadm`, `ipadm`, `dladm`, `luxadm`, `prtpicl` and `stmfadm` but cannot see how to do it.  There are many references to using fibre for storage, but none for IP.

Comment: have you looked at the oracle solaris documentation for ipfc? I have zero experience with it, but you might some tips: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E23097/agkbq.html#scrolltoc

Comment: Yes I have;  the two OSs have diverged somewhat now.  In particular `ipadm create-ip` does not work.